# Можно иметь два файла init.php в битрикс

Tags: битрикс

На сайте есть два файла Init.php в разных папках \bitrix\php_interface\init.php и  \local\php_interface\init.php в папке local инит работает, а в папке битрикс не работает, ничего не выводит даже если ставить лог в самом начале файла.Но я слышал что два файла вполне себе работают. Вопрос: могут ли два init.php в разных папках работать?

Answer (score 1):

Битрикс подключает `init.php` в `bitrix/modules/main/include.php` следующим образом:

```
if(file_exists(($_fname = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/init.php")))
    include_once($_fname);

if(($_fname = getLocalPath("php_interface/init.php", BX_PERSONAL_ROOT)) !== false)
    include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$_fname);

if(($_fname = getLocalPath("php_interface/".SITE_ID."/init.php", BX_PERSONAL_ROOT)) !== false)
    include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$_fname);
```

где используется функция `getLocalPath()`, в которой определяется наличие папки `local`, и если папка присутствует, то берется файл из неё. Если папка `local` отсутствует, то берется файл из папки `bitrix`. Так что использовать оба файла у вас не выйдет.

Но (см. первую строчку) вы можете подключить init.php, **расположенный в корне папки `bitrix`**, а также файлы `init.php`, расположенные в папке `local`.

Comment: Спасибо , но в корне папки bitrix  считается ядром, мне кажется это не правильно его там размещать